# Remove a django field from PyAMF ClassAlias

Tags: django, model, field, amf, pyamf

I use

```
my_classalias = pyamf.register_class(mymodel, mymodel._meta.object_name)
```

to make my django model into AMF serialized objects.

But the problem is mymodel contains a auto created pk field called `id`, but the Flash/Flex client can't accept such field, is there a way to remove that in PyAMF ClassAlias?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own solution:

```
m = my_model
ka = pyamf.register_class(m, m._meta.object_name)
ka.exclude_attrs = ['field1', 'field2']
```

or alternatively, in your `models.py`

```
class my_model(models.Model):
    field1 = IntegerField()
    field2 = TextField()
    class __amf__:
        exclude = ('field1', )
```

Note there is a [unpatched bug](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/quot-exclude-quot-doesn-t-work-for-relations-fields-in-Django-models-td2166547.html) in PyAMF for the m2m fields, you may have to manually edit file `pyamf/adapters/_django_db_models_base.py`, line `168`:

```
for name, relation in self.relations.iteritems():

    if name in self.exclude_attrs:
        continue
    if '_%s_cache' % name in obj.__dict__:
        attrs[name] = getattr(obj, name)
```

Hope this helps someone who has the same problem with me.